# The type initializer for '<Module>' threw an exception after Application pool timeout

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, iis, dll

I'm facing a problem with an external DLL after application pool time out.

I'm using VS2010 with a C# web application and .NET 2.0. This application include a external DLL (wrote in C++). This DLL is Referenced in the project so in the ObjectBrowser I could see the Assembly and all the functions. 
The DLL required anothers DLL's that I installed them in a c:\DLL directory and added this directory to the EnvironmentVariables "Path" at Application_Start() function.

The application works correctly all the times except after Application time out. (It has the 20 minutes default time out).

The next time I run the application after the time-out I got "The type initializer for '' threw an exception." in the function that do a new object of the DLL assambly

Another option to throw the error is to "End the process" for "w3wp.exe" in Windows Task Manager / Processes. After end the process and refresh the application the error is displayed.

Thanks

**Edited:**

Inner Exception:

```
at <CrtImplementationDetails>.ThrowModuleLoadException(String , Exception )
at <CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport.Initialize(LanguageSupport* )
at .cctor()The type initializer for '<Module>' threw an exception.
```

Comment: You will need to document the InnerException

Comment: Thanks Hans for your fast comment. I'm including the Inner Exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After implemented removing cookies I found the same issue with other scenarios.

So digging more I found the Real issue was my unmanaged DLL had a conflict with a Class that inherent from IPrincipal:

```
public class UserDataThirdParty : IPrincipal
```

So I found the solutions in these links:

[The type initializer for '' threw an exception](http://world.episerver.com/Blogs/Svante-Seleborg/Dates/2011/10/The-type-initializer-for-Module-threw-an-exception/)

and

[Error on DataPortal with Loading assembly msvcm80](http://forums.lhotka.net/forums/p/4366/21404.aspx)

So now the definition of my class is:

```
public class UserDataThirdParty : MarshalByRefObject, IPrincipal
```

Comment: Well damn. I had legit no idea where the error originated from. This saved my life.

Answer (score 0):

Finally the issue was resolved.

The problem was with a cookie. So at Application_Start() function I remove this cookie:

```
HttpCookie aCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName);
aCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(aCookie);
```

Comment: You should mark this answer as correct in that case :) That way it's not listed as unanswered.